# Django DRF: Cant see login option

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I cant see login option in this

[image]

I have the below

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated",
    ),
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ),
}
```

Comment: have you tried in incognito mode ?

Comment: yes. I have tried in incognito mode

Comment: for me if i directly hit the url `api.localhost:8025/api/v1/` it works

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) :

If you're intending to use the browsable API you'll probably also want to add REST framework's login and logout views. Add the following to your root urls.py file.

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

Note that the URL path can be whatever you want.